# Is there any case in which unbiased but larger MSE estimator preferred to biased and smaller MSE one?

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, bias-variance-tradeoff

Let saying we are interested in a population mean $\mu$ and we have two estimators $\hat{\mu}_{n}^b$ and $\hat{\mu}_{n}^{u}$ defined on $n$ samples such that

1. $\hat{\mu}_{n}^b$ : biased (i.e, $\mathbb{E}\hat{\mu}_{n}^b \neq \mu$)
2. $\hat{\mu}_{n}^u$ : unbiased (i.e, $\mathbb{E}\hat{\mu}_{n}^u = \mu$)
3. MSE of  $\hat{\mu}_{n}^b$ is smaller than MSE of $\hat{\mu}_{n}^u$ for all $n$. (i.e., $\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}^b - \mu\right]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}^u - \mu\right]^2$)
4. Both estimators are consistent. (i.e., $\hat{\mu}_{n}^b, \hat{\mu}_{n}^u \rightarrow \mu$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$)

In this setting, is there any case where $\hat{\mu}_{n}^u$ is preferred to $\hat{\mu}_{n}^b$? In other words, when do people consider unbiasedness of an estimator more valuable even though it suffers larger MSE?

Comment: If your loss function is asymmetric, and you know the direction of bias of your estimator, it may well be you'd prefer an unbiased estimator with higher MSE to one that is biased in the direction of higher loss.  This is true in inventory control (where in fact you prefer forecasts that are biased slightly high) due to the asymmetry in costs inflicted on you by a stockout and by holding an extra unit of inventory.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks for comments. Even though I asked in terms of MSE for a sake of simplicity, my question was meant to compare unbiasedness and low expected loss. Under the decision theory framework, minimizing expected loss is a ultimate goal but I wonder under which circumstance unbiasedness would be super important.